# User Issue on Ubuntu 20.4 VM

Tags: 20.04

I am attempting to follow posted instructions for a class and have the SEED Ubuntu VM installed and able to run. The default SEED user seems to work just fine, however whenever I attempt to follow step 2 of the instructions and create my own user with my name, I am able to create the user, but attempts to log into it result in just a black screen accompanied often by user preference windows that are misshapen.

I've tried to look into solutions for this only to come up short. Any insight you could provide on this on how I should proceed?

https://github.com/seed-labs/seed-labs/blob/master/manuals/vm/seedvm-manual.md

Comment: I'm confused - [Step 2](https://github.com/seed-labs/seed-labs/blob/master/manuals/vm/seedvm-manual.md#step-2-provide-a-name-and-select-the-os-type-and-version) of the linked instructions is about naming the **virtual machine**, not the user. You would not be able to log in to the machine (with pre-configured username `seed`) until [Appendix A](https://github.com/seed-labs/seed-labs/blob/master/manuals/vm/seedvm-manual.md#appendix-a-start-the-vm-and-take-snapshot). Only **then** would you be able to create new users.